# Scheme list manipulation program

Tags: list, scheme

I need to make a program that takes 2 variables, a list e.g. `L1`=`(1 2 3 4 5 6)` and a number e.g. `x`=`2`
where it takes the first `x` number of items from the list into a new list e.g. `L2`=`(1 2)` and output both lists:

```
(define split(lambda (list L1) x)
  (if(> x 0)
      (- x 1)
       (list L2(car(L1)))
             (cdr L1))
  (L1 
    L2))
```

I'm new to Scheme and just getting the hang of the brackets and list manipulation. It also gives me a multiple expression after identifier syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many syntax errors in your solution, it's simpler if I show you a correct version and explain the problems. For starters, this will be easier to implement if we split the problem in two procedures:

- `split-aux` returns the first `x` elements from `L1`. Notice that this does the same as the `take` function present in some interpreters
- `split` is the "main" function, it returns a two-element list: the first element is `L1` (the original list) and the second is the result of splitting `L1`

Some things to fix in your code:

- The indentation can be improved to make things clearer
- The parameter declaration is incorrect, it should be `(L1 x)`
- If `x` is greater than zero you must *advance* the recursion, by calling the procedure we're defining
- Because we're building a list as the output, use `cons` to stick together new elements
- When we finish the recursion we must return an empty list - again, because we're building a list as output

This is what I mean:

```
(define split
  (lambda (L1 x)
    (list L1 (split-aux L1 x))))

(define split-aux
  (lambda (L1 x)
    (if (> x 0)
        (cons (car L1) (split-aux (cdr L1) (- x 1)))
        '())))
```

Test it, it works as expected:

```
(split '(1 2 3 4 5) 2)
=> '((1 2 3 4 5) (1 2))
```

I suggest you pick a book to teach you the basics and the right way of thinking about a solution in Scheme. Grab a copy of *The Little Schemer* or *How to Design Programs* to get you started!